# issue in intialising character array from the structure through an array object

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, assignment-operator, string-literals

i am getting an issue while initialising the character array in the structure through the structure object

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <string.h>
    using namespace std;
    struct emp
    {
        int age;
        char name[10];
    };
    int main()
    {
        struct emp v[2];
    
    List item
    
        v[0].age = 9;
        v[0].name[] = "name1"; <-this is where i am getting error
        v[1].age = 10;
        v[1].name[]= "name2"; <-this is where i am getting error
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            cout << v[i].age << " " << v[i].name<<endl;
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: what issue do you get? Please do not confuse c and c++, they are two different languages. Your code is c++, not c. You are including a c header, the c++ variant of the header is called `<cstring>`, but I think you arent using anything from it anyhow

Comment: Is `List item` really part of this code?

Comment: as this is c++, is there any reason you are not using `std::string` ?

Comment: Why are you treating Emp.name like char[]

Comment: Such assignment to arrays is simply not intended in the language, neither C nor C++. You can, though, provide an *initialiser*: `emp v[] = { {9, "name1"}, {10, "name2"} };`.

Comment: You're using C++, but you're working with C strings. This kind of assignment: `v[0].name[] = "name1"` cannot be used with C strings. You should either use C++ strings or use appropriate functions to deal with C strings.

Comment: actually the problem was intially put forth by a friend and he was doing it in c, but i am more comfortable in cpp thats why i did it in cpp , not using string was a conscious decision i made so as to solve the question for him @463035818_is_not_a_number

Comment: when you are looking for a solution in c++ that does not use some c++ for whatever reason you should mention it in the question. The answer will be different for C++ or C or C++ without `std::string`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters there is at least a typo

```
    v[0].name[] = "name1"; <-this is where i am getting error
            ^^^^ 
    v[1].name[]= "name2"; <-this is where i am getting error
            ^^^^
```

Arrays do not have the assignment operator. So these assignment statements

```
v[0].name[] = "name1";
v[1].name[]= "name2";
```

are incorrect syntactically and semantically.

You could initialize the elements of the array when it is declared.

For example

```
struct emp v[2] =
{
    { 9, "name1" },
    { 10, "name2" }
};
```

Otherwise you could use the standard string function `strcpy`. For example

```
#include <cstring>

//...
v[0].age = 9;
strcpy( v[0].name, "name1" );
v[1].age = 10;
strcpy( v[1].name, "name2" );
```

Another approach is to use class `std::string` instead of the character array. For example

```
#include <string>

// ...
struct emp
{
    int age;
    std::string name;
};

int main()
{
    struct emp v[2];

    v[0].age = 9;
    v[0].name = "name1";
    v[1].age = 10;
    v[1].name= "name2";
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cout << v[i].age << " " << v[i].name<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Pay attention to that instead of the ordinary for loop you could use the range-based for loop.

For example

```
for ( const auto &item : v )
{
    cout << item.age << " " << item.name << endl;
}
```

Comment: why can't i just use  v[0].name = "name1";  with character array instead of std::string , pls help me with this

Comment: @ayeyo As I wrote in teh answer arrays do not have the assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

In Modern C++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

struct emp {
  int age;
  std::string name;
};

int main() {
  std::array<emp, 2> v{{{9, "name1"}, {10, "name2"}}};

  for (const auto& item : v) {
    std::cout << item.age << " " << item.name << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: after 10 years the term "modern" is a little worn out ;). Some explanation would help to make this a good answer. Code only answers may help the asker now with their specific issue, but to help them also with their next you need to explain the code

Comment: Maybe go a bit more modern and use `std::string_view` instead of `std::string` here ;) Of course this won't work, if the backing char array may be changed, which is not an issue for string literals...

Comment: actually the problem was intially put forth by a friend and he was doing it in c, but i  am more comfortable in cpp thats why i did it in cpp , not using string was a conscious decision i made so as to solve the question for him